# How to use lapply over a list of rasters

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, raster

I've got a raster and I need to compare the values of the first and last row. (I want to know, if there is a Cluster that connects top with bottom)
That's what I've done:

```
V1=getValues(r,row=1)
V1=V1[V1!=0]
V1=unique(V1)
```

and the same with the last row.
Then I do this:

```
V1 %in% V2
```

That's okay. It's working. But I need to do this with many many rasters.
I thought about creating a list with these several rasters and run the script above over every raster of the list. I thought I could do that with `lapply` but I don't know how to do that.

Or maybe there is a possibility to get kind of a dataframe back or something like this

```
raster     connected 
r1         TRUE
r2         FALSE
r3         FALSE
...        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FUN.raster <- function(r) {
  x <- getValues(r, row = 1)
  x <- x[x!=0]
  x <- unique(x)

  y <- getValues(r, row = nrow(r))
  y <- y[y!=0]
  y <- unique(y)

  x %in% y
}
```

and then

```
sapply(rasterlist, FUN.raster)
```

This gives you a boolean vector of `TRUE/FALSE` with the length of your `rasterlist`.Beware that this is untested, as you didn't provide any example data.